# How to get root shell after login as a normal desktop user and how to patch it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am new to Linux. I am interested in security too. I got to know from one of my friend that it is possible to get into root shell after login as a normal desktop user. I don't know how to do it. I only know its possible after exploiting some services.

When I search for the above topic, I come to that, first we need to find out SUID files, which are the executable files having special permissions. I used 'find / -perm +4000' command to get such files list.

I don know what to do after that and get into root shell. I need to find out such issues in my OS and need to patch it. Could you please help me?

Comment: The last time you asked this question - 2hrs ago - it was closed as 'off topic' because it's not a programming question suitable for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay, Then from where i can find a solution for it?

Comment: If you're asking how a normal desktop user can *become* the root user, that's well known but not considered a security issue *if used carefully and wisely*. Why do you want to know?

Comment: Your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752362/how-to-get-root-shell-after-login-as-a-normal-desktop-user) has a commend telling you where you can find answers. Why are asking the exact same question again over here?

Comment: Its a vulnerability of programming right?

Comment: The way to get started with securing your system isn't to root it, it's to install the updates provided by your distribution vendor.  The tone of your question makes me suspect that you're really just trying to learn how to break into Linux machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get your list of root suid programs (this is just one of many starting points when trying to get root on a system)  you have to find if any of them are vulnerable to [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (you can start searching the [CVE database](http://cve.mitre.org/) for their names) and get a shell payload to be executed when the hole is exploited (so you can get a root shell).

There are many resources on the topic and by googling for "buffer overflow" you'll get to them.

Answer (score 0):

There's no generic way to do this; it depends on what vulnerabilities exist on the system you've logged into, and that can vary from machine to machine.  You need to look at what version of the OS is running, what vulnerabilities are known in that OS version, and which patches haven't been installed on the machine in question.